# Android nested fragments - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a tabbed layout using `FragmentTabHost`. Everything worked fine, but then I realized that I want to switch multiple fragments in a single tab.

After seeing few examples of nested fragments, I implemented the below class which should, on one hand, become the single fragment added to the tab host, and on the other hand it is the parent fragment for the contents of the tab:

```
/**
 * Instances of this class are used as a containers for fragments inside app's tabs.
 *
 * The reason for using this intermediate class is that we need to switch multiple fragments
 * in a single tab. Since each tab is supposed to hold just a single fragment, this container will
 * be that fragment. The actual switching of fragments then happens here and not in app's tab.
 */
public class FragmentContainer extends Fragment {

    public static final String PARAM_CONTENT_FRAGMENT = "param_content_fragment";

    public static final String EXTRA_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT = "default_fragment";


    public static FragmentContainer newInstance(String class_name) {
        FragmentContainer container = new FragmentContainer();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
        bundle.putString(EXTRA_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT, class_name);
        container.setArguments(bundle);

        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_container, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Fragment f = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);
        if (f == null) {
            Class<? extends Fragment> claz = (Class<? extends Fragment>) getArguments().getSerializable(
                    PARAM_CONTENT_FRAGMENT);
            FragmentTransaction tx = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            try {
                f = claz.newInstance();
                f.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
                tx.add(R.id.fragment_content, f);
                tx.commit();
                getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();

        try {
            Field childFragmentManager = Fragment.class.getDeclaredField("mChildFragmentManager");
            childFragmentManager.setAccessible(true);
            childFragmentManager.set(this, null);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public void replaceContent(Class<? extends Fragment> claz, Bundle args) {
        FragmentTransaction tx = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        tx.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

        // save
        Fragment curFrag = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);
        if (curFrag != null) {
            tx.addToBackStack(curFrag.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }

        // change
        try {
            Fragment newFragment = claz.newInstance();
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
            tx.replace(R.id.fragment_content, newFragment, claz.getClass().getSimpleName());
            tx.commit();
            getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // Suppress "unchecked" warning. claz variable is checked for compatibility with Fragment class
    // inside the surrounding "if" statement
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    public void setDefaultContent(Bundle args) {

        Class<?> claz = null;

        try {
            claz = Class.forName(getArguments().getString(EXTRA_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Ensure that claz extends Fragment
        if (claz != null && Fragment.class.isAssignableFrom(claz) ) {
            Fragment childFragment = getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content);
            // Replace the content if the currently showed fragment is not the default
            if (!claz.isInstance(childFragment)) {
                replaceContent((Class<? extends Fragment>) claz, args);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("FragmentContainer/setDefaultContent", "default class is either null or does" +
                    "not extend Fragment");
        }
    }


}
```

This piece of code from the activity initializes the tab host:

```
    private void initializeTabHost(Bundle args) {
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);
        TabInfo tabInfo = null;
        Main.addTab(this, mTabHost,
                mTabHost.newTabSpec(HOME_TAB_TAG).setIndicator(getString(R.string.home_tab_indicator)),
                (tabInfo = new TabInfo(HOME_TAB_TAG, HomeFragment.class, args)));
        mMapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.mTag, tabInfo);

        // Default to home tab
        this.onTabChanged(HOME_TAB_TAG);

        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    }

    private static void addTab(Main activity, FragmentTabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
        // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
        tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
        String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

        // Check to see if we already have a fragment for this tab, probably
        // from a previously saved state.  If so, deactivate it, because our
        // initial state is that a tab isn't shown.
        tabInfo.mFragmentContainer = (FragmentContainer) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (tabInfo.mFragmentContainer != null && !tabInfo.mFragmentContainer.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(tabInfo.mFragmentContainer);
            ft.commit();
            activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec, tabInfo.mClass, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
        TabInfo newTab = (TabInfo) this.mMapTabInfo.get(tag);
        if (mLastTab != newTab) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            if (mLastTab != null) {
                if (mLastTab.mFragmentContainer != null) {
                    ft.detach(mLastTab.mFragmentContainer);
                }
            }
            if (newTab != null) {
                if (newTab.mFragmentContainer == null) {
                    newTab.mFragmentContainer = FragmentContainer.newInstance(newTab.mClass.getName());
                    ft.add(android.R.id.tabcontent, newTab.mFragmentContainer, newTab.mTag);
                } else {
                    ft.attach(newTab.mFragmentContainer);
                }
                newTab.mFragmentContainer.setDefaultContent(null);
            }

            mLastTab = newTab;
            ft.commit();
            this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

        } else {
            newTab.mFragmentContainer.setDefaultContent(null);
        }
    }
```

When I launch the app I immediately get an exception when `tx.commit();` is called from within `replaceContent` (it is done in order to show the first tab's default fragment).

I certainly missed some limitation of Android system when building this structure `Activity->FragmentTabHost->FragmentContainer->Fragment(s)`, or, maybe, misused one of the APIs, but I just can't find it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it: i was calling `newTab.mFragmentContainer.setDefaultContent(null);` before committing the addition of `newTab.mFragmentContainer` and making sure it is executed. In other words, I was manipulating the `ContainerFragment` before it was properly added to view hierarchy.